# Disable Jquery while portrait mode iPad/iPhone

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do i disable my jquery horizontal slider in portrait mode? 
Its driving me nuts, because i dont know any javascript, so i have no idea how to do it.

Thanks already,
Wouter

---

-edit-
Here is the Javascript:
[Javascript](http://www.wsdesigns.co.cc/js/swipe.js)

Comment: How about you show us some code so we can see what's what?

Comment: I added the code to the question.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution from [David Walsh](http://davidwalsh.name/orientation-change):

```
window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function() {
  if(window.orientation == 0 || window.orientation == 180){ //this is portrait
    //disable the slider here.
  }
  else{
    //enable the slider here
  }
}, false);
```

> During these changes, the window.orientation property may change. A
>   value of 0 [or 180] means portrait view, -90 means a the device is landscape
>   rotated to the right, and 90 means the device is landscape rotated to
>   the left.

Comment: You may want to check 180° for upside-down portrait mode as well.